# How to position elements inside div that is fixed?

Tags: html, css, position

I've got `div` that I need to be *fixed*. Now I want to create two sub-`div`s inside that `div`. Is it possible?

What I am trying to get is:

```
div { position: fixed; }
---------------------
- sub-div1 { position: ??? }
- sub-div2 { position: ??? }
---------------------
```

I tried another position properties but haven't got that yet.
UPD: solved.

Comment: whats the structure?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your inner positioning requirements, either `relative` or `absolute`,,, both 'consider' parents position / offset .. -> http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Feel free to accept this as the answer if it solved your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely nest divs inside of divs.

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
  </div>
</div>
```

There are 3 different kinds of [positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) absolute, relative and fixed. If you position something as fixed, its positioned relatively to the browser window. Anything else you position inside of that div will be located within, unless its positioned with absolute or something I believe, but that would only be visual, technically in the page structure it would still be inside. But here's an example you can save and try, its by no means an example of style btw.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1{
left: 100px;
top:150px;
position:fixed;
background:red;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="div1">
heellloooooooooooooooo<br><br><br><br>
<div style="float:left;background:yellow;">
woooooooooorld
</div>
<div style="float:right;background:blue;">
hahahahahah
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```